# Is it idiomatic to say "x is equal to 30 at least 900 times"?

Tags: word-usage

[A post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/458971/277710) says

> Assume the Bureau repeats the survey 1,000 times, the confidence levels of 90% means that the stated number is between (35,534,124 to 37,315,094) **at least 900 times**.

I am aware the idiomatic way to express that meaning would be

> the stated number is between (35,534,124 to 37,315,094) 90% of the time.

However, the quoted part is an explanation to "90% of the time". It is supposed to use a more simpler expression convey the idea.

So, Is it idiomatic to say "... at least 900 times" in that case? Could someone please give a hint? Thanks in advance.

Comment: With this kind of statistical analysis, mathematically-minded people usually think in terms of [***standard deviation***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) anyway. But non-specialists would probably prefer ***90% of the time*** - or the even simpler ***9 times out of 10*** (not usually *90 times out of 100* or *900 times out of 1000*).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Thank you. How do I convey the idea of "at lease"? Does "9 times out of 10 or more" would confuse the audience? "9 times and more" sounds like "9 times or 10 times", which is not what I was trying to say, right?